# Tomcat JSF 1 Erro com f:convertNumber

Tags: jsf, tomcat

Olá, uso minha aplicação no tomcat 6, preciso mudar para o tomcat 7 mas em todas os lugares que uso o f:convertNumber recebo o seguinte erro:

> /pages/pvt/ipd/cliente/consultar.xhtml @37,105 value="#{clientePocketController.cliente.codcliente}": **Can't set property 'codcliente' on class** 'br.com.mili.entities.geral.cliente.Cliente' to value '1.793'

**Editado**

```
<h:inputText id="txtCodCliente" value="#{clientePocketController.cliente.codcliente}" 
         converterMessage="Permitido apenas números.">
     <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" minIntegerDigits="0"  pattern="######" locale="pt_BR"/>
     <f:validateLength maximum="6" />
</h:inputText>
```

Estou usando JSF 1.2. Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Bruno, mas eu ja estou com o locale configurado no faces-config ( <default-locale>pt_BR</default-locale>) e testei também com o locale no convertNumber, mas não altera em nada. Tem alguma informação faltando que poderia ajudar?

Comment: Teria que saber com mais detalhes como está seu projeto, como a versão da EL no classpath dele. Se tiver usando a do Tomcat pode estar dando erro. Tente listar tudo que tem relação com binding de informações, versão de bibliotecas, o tipo de dado no seu bean, etc.

Comment: eu atualizei as lib no tomcat (fiz o mesmo para o tomcat 6 e 7), estou usando el-api-2.2.0.jar e el-impl-2.2.jar, JSF 1.2. O erro da em qualquer tipo da propriedade (Integer, BiDecimal, Double). Será que não é melhor eu criar meu próprio converter?!

Comment: Consegui, eu tinha alterado a lib el-api do tomcat para essa el-api-2.2.0, e foi esse o problema. Erro meu. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

Talvez o problema seja que você esteja setando o valor = '1.793' em um campo do tipo inteiro, mas o jsf já tem um conversor padrão para o tipo Integer que nesse caso não precisaria especificar.

Comment: Não é Paulo, eu coloco 1793, apenas na mensagem de erro que retorna 1.793. Se eu tiro o converter funciona...